# Symbolic function for matrices

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, symbolic-math

How to create symbolic function for matrices?
For example, I want to have matrix multiplication

```
A = sym('A',[5,1])
B = sym('B',[1,5])
f = symfun(A * B,[A, B])
```

But I have an error because `A` and `B` have different dimensions, and I can't use square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

`symfun` only supports scalar arguments, thus you can only define a symbolic function with 10 scalar arguments:

```
f = symfun(A * B,[A(:); B(:)])
```

I recommend to work with the symbolic expression instead and use `subs` to evaluate:

```
f=A*B
```

Further you can also use a function handle:

```
f=@(a,b)(a*b);
f(A,B)
```

Comment: A = sym('A',[5,1])
    B = sym('B',[1,5])
    f(a,b)=a*b;
    f(A,B)
Error using symengine (line 58)
Array sizes must match.

Comment: Sorry, pasted the wrong code here. `f(a,b)=a*b` is just another way to define a symbolic function which does not succeed.  Answer now contains the correct code.